# How to properly consume JAX-RS (RESTEasy) with Pentaho(kettle)

Tags: web-services, rest, pentaho, resteasy, kettle

I want to send data(table employees) via HTTP POST REQUEST to my API service, and save it to database.

piece of code:

```
@POST
@Consumes({ "application/json" })
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/full/json")
public Response recieveDataFJson(Employee employee) {
    System.out.println("Recieved employee with name: " + employee.getName());
    return Response.ok("works").build();
}
```

I'm using JSON output item to prepare the data for sending to the service, but I think the problem is that Pentaho is sending the JSON in the format:

```
{"Employee":[{"name":"mike"}]}
```

but service is just waiting for:

```
{"name":"mike"}
```

I tried to delete initial tag but then the sending item was:

```
{"":[{"name":"mike"}]}
```

my service have no authentication, the URL is correct

What can I do, or there is another way to do the same more efficiently?

Comment: Can you modify Pentaho's request data? I mean, change the JSON the Pentaho is sending.

Comment: yes but I didn't found the way to exactly tell pentaho how to write the json, just edit some parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a "tricky" way of solving my problem:

In pentaho:

pass table data to a JSON and send it as TEXT PLAIN

In service:

recieve the request as TEXT PLAIN and then parse String to JSON and JSON to JAVA  object:

```
JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(recievedString);
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
            mapper.setDateFormat(format);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("Employee");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Employee employee = mapper.readValue(jsonObject.toString(),
                        Employee.class); = new NegocioBean();
                    negocioBean.aplicarReglas(factOrdenesTransporte);
            }
```